# Migrating from OWIN .NET Framework to OpenIddict .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, owin, .net-6.0, openiddict

I have an existing .NET Framework Web API currently in production which is in the process of being upgraded to `.NET 6`.

The application uses the built-in .NET Framework OWIN solution for generating tokens and handles the authorisation for the `client_credential` flow.

We have a couple of custom MySql tables that hold the `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` info and another for granted token requests, e.g. storing the OWIN `ticket`, `scope` details etc.

**One limitation we have is that we are using EF Core 3.1.x which we cannot upgrade.**

I want to build a solution so that:

1. existing active OWIN tokens in the database can still be used for
   authorisation into the new .NET Core API using OpenIddict, once it goes live. (so
   that the end users are not impacted)
2. I also want to be able to generate new tokens using OpenIddict and
   store those tokens in the same existing MySql tables.

I don't know if this is possible and if so how to tackle it.

Has anyone here achieved a similar migration?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but one question is how you know which need to generate the new token and which one this need the old token?

Comment: Please expand on "One limitation we have is that we are using EF Core 3.1.x which we cannot upgrade." Are you saying you want to use EF Core 3.1x with .NET 6?